# Who takes care of a widow who has no brothers and no sons?

Tags: halacha, death

According to Halacha or Talmud, who takes care of a widow, whose husband had no brothers, and who herself has no brothers and no sons and no daughters?

Comment: Why do you think there is someone designated to take care of her? Would "the husband's estate" qualify even though it's not a person?

Comment: My understanding is that there could possible be  designated persons, who of course have the options to opt-out, such as in levirate marriages, etc... My question is directed to those who know the Talmud, Mishna, Halacha, etc...., who might know what ancient Jewish law might say about such.

Comment: Surely ancient Judaism had provision for such a widow?

Comment: @ninamag are you asking about her financial status, mainly who would provide for her?

Comment: Everything. Who would house her, who would maintain her, who would ....

Comment: Charity would go to the poor, the widow and the orphan. That's probably all you'll find

Comment: The estate would have to go to some heir. He would use the estate to take care of her. The only person with no heir is a ger, and she could take posession of the property just like anyone else.

Comment: @sabbahillel I understand just like many others that this would be the case, "The estate would have to go to some heir. He would use the estate to take car of her." But could you give me a bibliographic source for this in the Talmud or similar. Thanks.

Comment: Does not Hashem take care of the orphan and widow, and if she is poor probably the community needs to support her

Comment: @hazoriz I agree with you, because in part your answer quotes the Torah. On the second part of your answer, you used the word "probably" as in "if she is poor probably the community needs to support her". Why the unsure status of your answer? Is Gemora, Halacha, etc., unsure of what to do with a Jewish widow "whose husband had no brothers, and who herself has no brothers and no sons and no daughters"?

Comment: @ninamag not because the halacha is not sure but becouse I have low self esteem, interesting law I read resently (if I understood correctly) a mother has no responsibilities to her children if they do not have a father https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Even_HaEzer.82.8

Comment: @hazoriz that really sounds awful, but then I did not read the entire context only this: אִם לֹא רָצְתָה הָאֵם שֶׁיִּהְיוּ בָּנֶיהָ עִמָּהּ אַחַר שֶׁגְּמָלָתָן, אֶחָד זְכָרִים וְאֶחָד נְקֵבוֹת, הָרְשׁוּת בְּיָדָהּ, וְנוֹתֶנֶת אוֹתָם לַאֲבִיהֶם, אוֹ מַשְׁלֶכֶת אוֹתָם לַקָּהָל אִם אֵין לָהֶם אָב, וְהֵם מְטַפְּלִים בָּהֶם, אֶחָד זְכָרִים וְאֶחָד נְקֵבוֹת:

Comment: @ninamag but on the other hand this is supper woman's liberation (rights) feminism

Answer (score 1):

As sabbahillel pointed out, everyone has a heir besides for a convert, so there would always be some distant relative that would inherit the estate. The Rambam states (ishus 18:1-3) that a widow lives off the the assets of the heirs until she gets the kesubah (prenuptial agreement). They have no right to force her to get her kesubah in order that they shouldn't need to provide for her, she gets food as long as she wants to, provided that she does not ask for her kesubah (magid mishna ibid). The Rambam adds that she stays in the house she used to live in when her husband was alive and uses all the objects in the house and even uses the slaves of the house as she used to before.

[Rambam Sefer Nashim Hislcosh Ishut 18:1-3](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/952892/jewish/Ishut-Chapter-Eighteen.htm)

Comment: For the OP's (and others') benefit, you should probably explain "kesubah". I suspect OP has never heard of this.

Comment: @Bach, where can one read online "ishus 18:1-3"?

Comment: @ninamag I added the link to the Rambam at chabad.org

Comment: @Bach just like @ msh210 said, at least to make this post more complete (and not because anybody here "has never heard of this"), can you, in one-sentence or two-sentences, explain "Kesuba", as well as, what is the most appropriate one-word-translation or two-word-translation of "Kesuba" into English.

Comment: @ninamag isn't "prenuptial agreement" sufficient?

Comment: @Bach Yes, for today, a "prenuptial agreement" might be sufficient. As per my question, I was wondering if there was an example of such a scenario in the "Halacha or Talmud".